# PAM UMASK not respected on NFS

Tags: nfs, samba, pam

I have make directory enabled in `/etc/pam.d/common-session` with the `session optional        pam_mkhomedir.so umask=000`

I using Samba Winbind to authenticate domain users. So, in `smb.conf`, i have
`template homedir  = /nfs/upload/%U`

Note: its intentional that home dir is set to `777` permissions, it will be on a NFS mount and need full access for everyone

**The problem is**

If `/nfs` is a local directory, the home directory permissions are `777` as expected

If `/nfs` is an NFS mount, then the directory is created with `700`  -- Not sure how to fix this

thank you all

Comment: Yeah I think the nfs protocol or the nfs server does not completely support umask. Maybe its protecting you from yourself? :)

Comment: I also tested my self configured NFS on linux, that seems to work.
But, the one I'm using is a vendor specific (http://zadarastorage.com/) NFS + SMB supported share, not sure if its a vendor issue.